# Disable Fn + esc to power off

Tags: keyboard, shutdown

I make heavy use of F keys for my windows manager but when I miss the key and press F + esc instead of F1, my notebook shuts down.

Is there a way to disable the possibility to shut my system down with this key combination?

Comment: What is the F key? For me, this is the key with the letter F.